# Matching Whole Dictionary Keys in String using List Comprehension

Tags: python

I have a dictionary called `cc_dict` and am trying to use list comprehension to iterate over each key to find a match in a string called `new_string`. The line below works but it also matches keys that are part of whole words. I want to match whole words only.

So, for example, the key "test" is matched in the string "text for testing".

How can I do this?

Example one:

```
cc_dict = {“test one”: “SSK1”, “result”: “TGG”, “pass”: “PSS1”, “fail”: “FL1”}

new_string = "If test one is complete."

output = [te for key, te in cc_dict.items() if key in new_string]
```

Desired result: SSK1

Example two:

```
cc_dict = {“test one”: “SSK1”, “result”: “TGG”, “pass”: “PSS1”, “fail”: “FL1”}

new_string = "There has been a failure in annex 1."

output = [te for key, te in cc_dict.items() if key in new_string]
```

Desired result: no result but as "fail" is contained in the word "failure" the list comprehension currently returns FL1.

Comment: Please add sample input and result, otherwise people have to guess.

Comment: I see that you have your answer, but please pay attention to pasting code snippets.  Both `cc_dict`s have typographic quotes, and can't be copypasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following,

This method will use regex to determine if the whole string that you are looking for is available in the string that you are searching in,

```
def string_found(string1, string2):
    if re.search(r"\b" + re.escape(string1) + r"\b", string2):
        return True
    return False
```

This can now be used in your dict comprehension,

```
output = [te for key, te in cc_dict.items() if string_found(key, new_string)]
```

Results,

```
# scenario 1
cc_dict = {“test one”: “SSK1”, “result”: “TGG”, “pass”: “PSS1”, “fail”: “FL1”}

new_string = "If test one is complete."

output = [te for key, te in cc_dict.items() if string_found(key, new_string)]

output
>>['SSK1']

# scenario 2
cc_dict = {“test one”: “SSK1”, “result”: “TGG”, “pass”: “PSS1”, “fail”: “FL1”}

new_string = "There has been a failure in annex 1."

output = [te for key, te in cc_dict.items() if string_found(key, new_string)]

output
>>[]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can split your match string into words using `split`:

```
[te for key, te in cc_dict.items() if key in new_string.split()]
```

Comment: Thanks @jprebys. This won't work as some of the keys are multiple words.